# Change the value of cell then concatenate into one row SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, case, for-xml-path

So I'm trying to do several things at once and I'm not sure how to put them together.

My first step was to take multiple cells and combine them into 1 row based on id.

```
USE MAIN;
Select ACT.ID AS Activity

,STUFF ((       Select ',' + LE.Name AS [text()]

               FROM ActivityDemographicEthnicity ADE
                LEFT OUTER JOIN LookupEthnicity LE
                ON LE.ID  = ADE.ethinicityId 

                WHERE ACT.ID = ADE.ActivityID

                FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

            AS Ethnicity

FROM Activity ACT
```

This works well and produces something like this:

```
ID    Ethnicity
------------------------------------------
123   African, African American, Caucasian
125   Caucasian 
128   NULL
```

BUT I would like something like this:

```
ID           Ethnicity
----------------------------------------
123          African American, Caucasian
125          Caucasian
128          General Market
```

Where I've defined new values via a case statement:

```
USE Main;
(Select CASE 
            When LE.Name is null THEN 'General Market'
            When LE.Name = 'African' THEN 'African American'
            When LE.Name = 'American Indian/Native American' Then 'American Indian'
            WHEN LE.NAME = 'Cambodian' Then 'Asian'
            When LE.Name = 'Chinese' Then 'Asian'
            When LE.Name = 'Filipino' Then 'Asian'
            When LE.Name = 'Hmong' Then 'Asian'
            WHEN LE.NAME = 'Japanese' THEN 'Asian'
            WHEN LE.Name = 'Korean' Then 'Asian'
            WHEN LE.Name = 'Laotian' Then 'Asian'
            WHEN LE.Name = 'Vietnamese' Then 'Asian'
            WHEN LE.Name = 'Armenian' Then 'Other'
            WHEN LE.Name = 'Russian' Then 'Other'
            WHEN LE.Name = 'Ukranian' Then 'Other'
            WHEN LE.Name = 'Other (specify)' Then 'Other'
            Else LE.Name
            End 'Ethnicity'

            From ActivityDemographicEthnicity ADE

            LEFT JOIN LookupEthnicity LE
                ON LE.ID = ADE.ID)`
```

Both queries work individually but how would I combine them into one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a whirl:

```
Select ACT.ID AS Activity,
ISNULL(STUFF((Select distinct ',' + CASE 
                When LE.Name is null THEN 'General Market'
                When LE.Name = 'African' THEN 'African American'
                When LE.Name = 'American Indian/Native American' Then 'American Indian'
                WHEN LE.NAME = 'Cambodian' Then 'Asian'
                When LE.Name = 'Chinese' Then 'Asian'
                When LE.Name = 'Filipino' Then 'Asian'
                When LE.Name = 'Hmong' Then 'Asian'
                WHEN LE.NAME = 'Japanese' THEN 'Asian'
                WHEN LE.Name = 'Korean' Then 'Asian'
                WHEN LE.Name = 'Laotian' Then 'Asian'
                WHEN LE.Name = 'Vietnamese' Then 'Asian'
                WHEN LE.Name = 'Armenian' Then 'Other'
                WHEN LE.Name = 'Russian' Then 'Other'
                WHEN LE.Name = 'Ukranian' Then 'Other'
                WHEN LE.Name = 'Other (specify)' Then 'Other'
                ELSE LE.Name
                END  
               FROM ActivityDemographicEthnicity ADE
               LEFT OUTER JOIN LookupEthnicity LE ON LE.ID  = ADE.ethnicityId 
               WHERE ACT.ID = ADE.ActivityID
               FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,''), 'General Market') AS Ethnicity
FROM Activity ACT
```

You need to wrap the whole `STUFF` function in an `ISNULL` to catch the cases where an Activity doesn't have a corresponding ActivityDemographicEthnicity.  And `select distinct` inside the `STUFF` to remove duplicates.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a95cb/1/0)

Comment: that works perfectly. The whole putting ISNULL around the Stuff came to me as I fell asleep last night but hadn't figured out the distinct! And I appreciate that you gave an explanation for the needed changes!

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you could simply replace your original query's call to the `LE.Name` field with your `CASE` statement, as in the following:

```
USE MAIN;
SELECT 
    ACT.ID AS Activity,
    STUFF 
      (
        (       
            SELECT ',' + 
                CASE 
                    When LE.Name is null THEN 'General Market'
                    When LE.Name = 'African' THEN 'African American'
                    When LE.Name = 'American Indian/Native American' Then 'American Indian'
                    WHEN LE.NAME = 'Cambodian' Then 'Asian'
                    When LE.Name = 'Chinese' Then 'Asian'
                    When LE.Name = 'Filipino' Then 'Asian'
                    When LE.Name = 'Hmong' Then 'Asian'
                    WHEN LE.NAME = 'Japanese' THEN 'Asian'
                    WHEN LE.Name = 'Korean' Then 'Asian'
                    WHEN LE.Name = 'Laotian' Then 'Asian'
                    WHEN LE.Name = 'Vietnamese' Then 'Asian'
                    WHEN LE.Name = 'Armenian' Then 'Other'
                    WHEN LE.Name = 'Russian' Then 'Other'
                    WHEN LE.Name = 'Ukranian' Then 'Other'
                    WHEN LE.Name = 'Other (specify)' Then 'Other'
                ELSE LE.Name
                END AS [text()]
            FROM 
                ActivityDemographicEthnicity ADE
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                LookupEthnicity LE ON 
                    LE.ID  = ADE.ethinicityId 
            WHERE ACT.ID = ADE.ActivityID

            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ),1,1,''
      ) AS Ethnicity
FROM Activity ACT
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: It has no syntactical errors but it gives  
 
 ' **Asian,Asian,Latino**'
instead of
   '**Asian,Latino**'
and it doesn't take care of NULL.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize DISTINCT was a requirement.  I won't update my original answer, as the comment by @Jerrad makes the appropriate changes and he even used a SQL Fiddle :)  His code looks good.